# DynamicReport Barcode width Issue

Tags: java, jasper-reports, barcode, dynamic-reports

I am using DynamicReport 4.0 and the following code to print a label. But I cannot increase the width of the barcode. Is there any way to increase the width of barcode in Dynamic Report?

```
    private ComponentBuilder<?, ?> getList(String title, String content){
        return DynamicReports.cmp.horizontalList(DynamicReports.cmp.text(title), DynamicReports.cmp.text(":"), DynamicReports.cmp.text(content));
    }

private void showLabel(){
    JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
        TextFieldBuilder<String> heading = DynamicReports.cmp.text("XYZ Company Ltd.");
        StyleBuilder headingstyle= DynamicReports.stl.style().setFontSize(16).setBold(true).setUnderline(true).setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP);
        heading.setStyle(headingstyle);

        report.setPageFormat(283, 425, PORTRAIT);
        report.setPageMargin(DynamicReports.margin().setLeft(14).setTop(14).setRight(14).setBottom(14));
        report.setTemplate(DynamicReports.template().setBarcodeWidth(400).setBarcodeHeight(40));

        //report.title(heading);
        VerticalListBuilder list = DynamicReports.cmp.verticalList();
        list.setGap(15);
        list.add(
                heading,
                getList("Client", "Anirban Chakraborty"),
                getList("Batch No.", "T7170B1000"),
                getList("Drawing No.", "51004A-777777-0111-B1000"),
                getList("Mark No.", "170B1000"),
                getList("Qty.", "1"),
                getList("Part Sr. NO.", "1/1"),
                getList("Rev.", "1.0"),
                getList("Wt.", "1.900"),
                DynamicReports.bcode.code128("T7170B1000").setStyle(DynamicReports.stl.style().setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
        );
        report.title(list);
        try{
            report.show(false);
        }catch(DRException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, we have to use `setModuleWidth(Double)`. For the above code it will be,

```
DynamicReports.bcode.code128("T7170B1000").setModuleWidth(3d).setStyle(DynamicReports.stl.style().setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
```